# Proof: $\lambda = \frac 1 2 (d(X,A)^2-d(X,B)^2+1)$ for $d(A,B)=1$

Tags: geometry

I want to prove (in one dimensional geometry) for $d(A,B)=|b-a|=1$ and $x=a+\lambda(b-a)$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$, where $d(X,B)$ is the distance between point $X$ and point $B$.

$$\lambda=\frac 1 2 (d(X,A)^2-d(X,B)^2+1)$$

I tried $d(X,A)+d(X,B)=1$, used binomial formula and got stuck. But I had no other idea how to get $d(X,A)^2+d(X,B)^2$.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: You forgot a minus in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $x=a+\lambda(b-a)$ implies $\lambda=d(X,A)=1-d(X,B)$. Plugging in gives

$$\frac{1}{2}(d(X,A)^2-d(X,B)^2+1)=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda^2-(1-\lambda)^2+1)=\lambda$$

Comment: Oh, that was helpful. I tried to use all the time $x=a+\lambda(b-a)$ and got stuck every time. Thanks anyway.